# Execute filter in theme as last

Tags: themes, filters

Is it possible the execute the called add_filter in theme after all plugins they've been loaded?

I use [one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-gallery-custom-links/) of the plugins from repository to can add the ability to define custom target links for gallery item but this one packs additional things which breaks my angular routing so I want to remove theme.

the rule should work I have been tested.
dumping html shows the plugins override is not present at this state.

I have in my functions.php

```
function attachment_link_sanitize($html) {
  $html = preg_replace("/class=\"no-lightbox\" target=\"_self\"/", "", $html);
  return $html;
}

add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link', 'attachment_link_sanitize',PHP_INT_MAX+1);
```

**Sorry for disturbing I've been checking the plugins JS and seems like everything comes from Jquery**

Comment: are you sure you are putting this code in the correct functions.php? is it firing at all?

Comment: yes is in the right place. Is in my custom active themes functions.php

Answer (score 1):

Yes set priority to something like 999 or something really high. The default priority is 10, and you currently have yours at 1 and therefore will occur first.

The priority is explained in the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter notably:

> $priority
>       (integer) (optional) Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower
>   numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same
>   priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the
>   filter.
>
> Default: 10

Comment: already tried the highest value won't seems t work